# Javascript regex question: strip special symbols and URL's

Tags: javascript, regex

What I need is something that will match words that contain special symbols (except ?, ! and .) and URL's.
Here's what I already have, but it doesn't quite work.

```
re = new RegExp('(http://\S+|\S*[^\w\s,.":]\S*)');

text = '@hello how are you? http://example.com';
clean = text.replace(re, '');
```

The current output is:

```
> 'hello how are you? http://example.com'
```

The output should be:

```
> '  how are you? '
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use global in the RE

```
text.replace(/(http:\/\/\S+|\S*[^\w\s,.":?]\S*)/g,'');
```

I also added "?" to your set since it seems you want that included.

Answer (score 1):

```
re = /(http:\/\/\S+|\S*[^\w\s,\.\?":]\S*)/ig;

text = '@hello how are you? http://example.com';
clean = text.replace(re, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about JavaScript, in Java I'll do this:

```
clean = input.replaceAll("(http://\\S+|\\S*[^\\w\\s\\?,.\"!:]\\S*)", "");
```

If you don't need to escape special characters, remove the backslashes.

Regards!

Comment: This deleted the @hello from my example, but the URL still remains

Comment: You have to use replaceAll or set the global flag, otherwise only the first occurrence will be replaced.